# Fancybox isn`t working only shows background

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, prestashop

I did try to create a simple fancybox did add some libraries but they only created background without the fancybox. This is my html code
`

```
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/newmodule/views/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script src="/modules/newmodule/views/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
            <script src="/modules/newmodule/views/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
            <script src="/modules/newmodule/views/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
            <script src="/modules/newmodule/views/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
            <a href="{$link->getPageLink('contact')}?content_only=1" id="contact-us-popup">Contact us</a>
          <script src="/modules/newmodule/views/js/new.js" type="text/javascript">
          </script>`
```

and this is jquery code

```
(function(jQuery) {
jQuery(document).ready(function()  {
        jQuery('#contact-us-popup').fancybox({
            type: 'ajax',
            autoDimensions: false,
            autoSize: false,
            width: 600,
            height: "auto"
        });
})
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Comment: did you forget to load `jquery`?

Comment: And if not - have you checked if the AJAX request is actually happening (browser dev tools, network panel), and what response it got?

Comment: Yeah, I load jquery but it not shows in this code I don`t why

Comment: I did checked the AJAX request and everything fine